# Is there a way to select/list which points are spatially related to the start point / end point of line type entities using oracle spatial?

Tags: sql, oracle, gis, spatial

I have two sets of spatially related entities that represent elements of a sewer system:
Pipes [VETROCOCOLECTOR] and Manholes [VECAMARANORMAL].

Each set of entities has, in total, about 20 000 records.
(Globally it corresponds to a number of independent, unconnected systems: imagine sewer systems for different cities in the same state.)

My aim is to get some attributes from the manholes for any given pipe using sql (oracle spatial). It’s of critical importance to flag/list which manholes are located **Upstream / Downstream** for further hydraulic studies.

I’m using oracle 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 – 64 bit production.

My code is as follows:

```
SELECT /*+ ORDERED */
B.IPID AS PIPE_ID, B.CODIGO_INSAAR AS PIPE_CODE,
'VECAMARANORMAL' as POINT_TYPE, A.IPID AS MANHOLE_ID, A.CODIGO_INSAAR AS MANHOLE_CODE, 'Upstream' as POSITION
  FROM VECAMARANORMAL A, VETROCOCOLECTOR B
  WHERE SDO_RELATE(A.Geometry, ST_StartPoint(B.Geometry), 'mask=ANYINTERACT') = 'TRUE' and B.IPID in (50110129,50110130,50085788)
UNION
SELECT /*+ ORDERED */
B.IPID AS PIPE_ID, B.CODIGO_INSAAR AS PIPE_CODE,
'VECAMARANORMAL' as POINT_TYPE, A.IPID AS MANHOLE_ID, A.CODIGO_INSAAR AS MANHOLE_CODE, 'Downstream' as POSITION
  FROM VECAMARANORMAL A, VETROCOCOLECTOR B
  WHERE SDO_RELATE(A.Geometry, ST_Endpoint(B.Geometry), 'mask=ANYINTERACT') = 'TRUE' and B.IPID in (50110129,50110130,50085788);
```

The first part of the union relates spatially a manhole with the startpoint of a pipe, the second with the endpoint of a pipe, using the functions ST_StartPoint and ST_Endpoint, respectively. (functions by Simon Greener)

Here are the results of my small sample

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OWZO.jpg)

| Pipe_ID | PIPE_CODE | POINT_TYPE | MANHOLE_ID | MANHOLE_CODE | POSITION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50085788 | 490 - 480 | VECAMARANORMAL | 50109999 | 490 | Upstream |
| 50085788 | 490 - 480 | VECAMARANORMAL | 50110000 | 480 | Downtream |
| 50110129 | 480.10 - 480 | VECAMARANORMAL | 50109998 | 480.1 | Upstream |
| 50110129 | 480.10 - 480 | VECAMARANORMAL | 50110000 | 480 | Downtream |
| 50110130 | 480 - 470 | VECAMARANORMAL | 50110000 | 480 | Upstream |
| 50110130 | 480 - 470 | VECAMARANORMAL | 50110001 | 470 | Downtream |

I’m able to do this for a small number (3) of selected pipes (although it takes around 50 seconds).

I would like to do the same for some selected systems and, ideally, for the overall network.

Obviously there’s something I need to change so that this can perform at scale, in an acceptable period of time.

Please advise me on how to do it.
Thanks a lot in advance and take care.
Best regards,
Pedro

Comment: Can you at least show us the execution plan for one of the branches of your SQL?

Comment: My plan is to:
Compare a table of points (vecamaranormal A) with the start and end points of a line table (Vetrococolector B)

If spatially connected to the start point of the Vetrococolector, flag the vecamaranormal as Upstream
SDO_RELATE(A.Geometry, ST_StartPoint(B.Geometry), 'mask=ANYINTERACT') = 'TRUE'

If spatially connected to the end point of the Vetrococolector, flag the vecamaranormal as Downstream
SDO_RELATE(A.Geometry, ST_Endpoint(B.Geometry), 'mask=ANYINTERACT')

Comment: Pedro, I'm not talking about what you want, that is understood, I'm talking about the query execution plan as built by the database optimizer. [Look here](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/how-to-generate-a-useful-sql-execution-plan) for examples.

Comment: Hey Salem, thanks for the clarification. At first I was using 2 view - I did the same query but with the equivalent bare bones tables (only with ID and Geometry columns) and now it works just fine. It was your tip about the query execution plan that did it for me - thanks a lot. Best regards